# SQL Server 2005 Stored Procedures running concurrently causes delays

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, concurrency

I have a stored procedure in my system that runs long already which is somewhat expected since it deals with lots of data and an export process. For arguments sake the procedure will run about 10 seconds by itself. There are times when I see this procedure called back to back with the same parameters.

Call 1 - Start 12:00:10; Duration 30 seconds

Call 2 - Start 12:00:15; Duration 10 seconds

It appears that the first call is waiting for the second call to complete before it can finish. I have blocked process report running and do not get any hits there from profiler; Also when I check sys.dm_exec_requests I do not see the SPID's being blocked by one another and the longest wait_type is async_network_io.

The stored procedure uses both #temp and @temp tables. I'm stuck what else should I check or change to get this under control?

Comment: Could be the second call gets to take better advantage of the cache. Do you have any other tasks starting at 12:00? How long does a single call of that SP take starting at a random time with a cold cache? Also think about pasting the *contents* of the SP into your question.

Comment: "the longest wait_type is async_network_io" - that is often a symptom of transferring too much data, I.e. SELECT * on large table(s).

Comment: @MitchWheat; yes this procedure has a dual function of sorts. 1) returns 20 rows from page 1. 2) There is internal logic that turns this into a data dump of sorts; where all of the client data is returned.

Comment: @MitchWheat, I spoke with my team yesterday and one of my coworkers played around with breaking the object up and said that it didn't change the performance of the data dump portion. With that said I think we need to test the issue of overlapping calls.

Comment: The reason I have not posted the procedure is because it is huge, not something I'm happy about but something I inherited from previous folks.

Answer (score 1):

"the longest wait_type is `async_network_io`" - that is often a symptom of transferring too much data, e.g. `SELECT *` on large table(s) or wide table(s).

Update in response to your comment:

> "yes this procedure has a dual function of sorts. 1) returns 20 rows
>   from page 1. 2) There is internal logic that turns this into a data
>   dump of sorts; where all of the client data is returned.

It sounds like you are being affected by parameter sniffing and an inappropriate cached query plan. Split your procedure into 2 separate stored procedures. That way each can have their own cached query plan.

Also note: table variables don't get statistics created for them, so sometimes you can see significant performance improvements by converting to use a temp table.

Comment: I thought about doing this to see if that would improve performance but wanted to go to the well of wisdom before touching this object.

Comment: about the Table variables, right they don't get stats updates but one of the issues I have seen with temp tables in the exec plans is that SQL Server appears to have cached the object. So in run 1 there were 100 rows in the temp table and it is cached, in Run 2 there are now 10000 rows and SQL Server is still showing the estimates based on 100 rows from the first run.